# Windows 7 - fonts missing after new install

Tags: windows-7, windows

Installed Windows Update and NVidia display drivers. Nothing else.

Fonts appear to be size 0 and I can't open many menus properly.

[image: Screenshot]

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I managed to - blindly - customise the appearance with a different font (Trebuchet MS).

Some of the fonts - like Segeo UI and Tahoma, were in fact *missing*.

There are still Windows Updates remaining that weren't installed, but I couldn't see to install them.

Once installed, things were fine.